# It is unable to creating index using Apache solr server running on separate port 8983

Tags: solr

I am working on eCommerce application using Broadleaf Commerce framework, I need to implement  searching functionality for required products using Apache solr. I have just followed the configuration what I found here
 http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/catalog-and-search

Now it is able to connect with solr server running on port 8983 but, when creating index it is throwing

"ERROR - 2014-07-19 02:37:23.729; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=1] unknown field 'namespace'
"
Exception,

But I could found "field" with name "namespace" in "schema.xml" file, like bellow

```
<fields>
    <field name="namespace" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="productId" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="category" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="explicitCategory" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="searchable" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_searchable" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_l" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_t" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_d" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_p" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

    <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="false" />
</fields>

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<types>
    <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />

    <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" />

    <!-- Default numeric field types. For faster range queries, consider the 
        tint/tlong/tdouble types. -->
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />

    <!-- Numeric field types that index each value at various levels of precision 
        to accelerate range queries when the number of values between the range endpoints 
        is large. See the javadoc for NumericRangeQuery for internal implementation 
        details. Smaller precisionStep values (specified in bits) will lead to more 
        tokens indexed per value, slightly larger index size, and faster range queries. 
        A precisionStep of 0 disables indexing at different precision levels. -->
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />

    <!-- The format for this date field is of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, 
        and is a more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime 
        http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime The trailing "Z" designates UTC 
        time and is mandatory. Optional fractional seconds are allowed: 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z 
        All other components are mandatory. Expressions can also be used to denote 
        calculations that should be performed relative to "NOW" to determine the 
        value, ie... NOW/HOUR ... Round to the start of the current hour NOW-1DAY 
        ... Exactly 1 day prior to now NOW/DAY+6MONTHS+3DAYS ... 6 months and 3 days 
        in the future from the start of the current day Consult the DateField javadocs 
        for more information. Note: For faster range queries, consider the tdate 
        type -->
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />

    <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" />

    <!-- A general text field that has reasonable, generic cross-language defaults: 
        it tokenizes with StandardTokenizer and down cases. -->
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>
```

schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files placed in src/main/resource folder

I could not find out the cause of Exception.
Any one can please help me.

And let me know if anything I need change in configuration and file structure.

Its great help for me if any one make me aware on the complete configurations, file structure with Apache solr server using broadleafCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add string as a fieldtype

```
   <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
```